# create a custom membership and profile provider in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I have a custom database schema that I want to use for the Custom Membership Provider.

Can anyone give a step by step procedure to do so because when I tried to create a class library project and extended my `CustomProvider` there was no `MembershipProvider`, just the `SqlMembershipProvider` and the `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider`, even with all the references attached.

Please help me guys with it.

Comment: Did you using System.Web.Security. See this for more comprehensive http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The custom membership provider creation is explained in this [video](http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider) by chris pels. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have gone through the video but the problem is that I cannot extend the `MembershipProvider` abstract class and nor able to `Implement Abstract Class`

Comment: Did you add reference to System.Web dll and added the using statements ? This is the class you need to reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx

Comment: yeah I added those references. `System.Web` and `System.Configuration`

Comment: Hi you need to reference System.Web.ApplicationServices dll too.

Answer (score 1):

In .net4 it seems to have been put into the `System.Web.ApplicationServices` dll even though the namespace is `System.Web.Security` while the SqlMembershipProvider still sits in `System.Web.Security`.

```
namespace System.Web.Security
    Member of System.Web.ApplicationServices

public class SqlMembershipProvider : System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider
    Member of System.Web.Security
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works now. Finally I can extend `MembershipProvider` class.

Comment: There seems to be no `Initialize` method in .net4 .. whats your say..??